# Python Selenium - Getting TimeoutException for elements belonging to a particular section of a webpage

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, timeoutexception

I've been trying to click this particular button that belongs to a toggle switch in a website.

`<button _ngcontent-plj-c265="" type="button" class="glyphicon glyph-mini ng-star-inserted expand" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Title Expand or collapse filter card" style="visibility: visible;" pbi-focus-tracker-idx="6"></button>`

This exists in the "filter" section of the website and I've adopted several methods and tags to perform this operation, some of which I've put here:

`1. sample1 = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(("xpath", '//*[@id="exploreFilterContainer"]/div[2]/div/filter[14]/div/div[1]/div[1]/button[1]'))).click()`

`2. sample2 = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(("css selector", 'button.expand'))).click()`

`3.sample3 = driver.find_element("xpath",'//[@id="exploreFilterContainer"]/div[2]/div/filter[14]/div/div[1]/div[1]/button[1]').click()`

Method 3 gave me a NoSuchElementException. Hence, I adopted methods 1 and 2 but got a TimeoutException for both. The button has no ID, so I couldn't fetch it that way, too.

But what I noticed was that there is an attribute in the button, **aria-expanded="true"** which when, I'm assuming, taking a value "false" will help operate the toggle button. But the catch is it can only do that if Selenium identifies the element itself, which brings us back to square one.

I'd highly appreciate any fruitful answer for my predicament. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share a link to that page and ALL your Selenium code?

Comment: @Prophet well, the page is a little confidential and I'm afraid, I can't share the link, but all of my selenium code helps login to the page and navigate to the filter section then this error happened, and all of my code resembles method 3. The webpage is divided into three sections and one of them is the filter section.

Comment: I understand. But without that we cannot debug and try understand what is going on there.

Comment: unfortunately, just the button code does not help with the timeout exception - because if we put this code on HTML, it works well, so something on DOM makes it to go for the timeout. I would suggest checking the DOM before this button. you might have some clue there.

Comment: @simpleApp will pyshadow help?

Comment: you can give that a try only if its shadow DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by switching to the `<iframe>` the element was within using this:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(0)   #switching to the iframe here
tb = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="exploreFilterContainer"]/div[2]/div/filter[15]/div/div[1]/div[1]/button[1]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", tb) #using JS to click the button
```

and it's advised that after all the operations pertaining to the element is performed that we switch back to normal as:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Thanks to @Prophet @simpleApp for your efforts in trying to help me out :)